# jQuery trigger change event function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a change function in javascript who permit me to do an action when the user click on a chekbox who's name is "*nameCheckbox*" so i have this script.

```
$("input[name='nameCheckbox']").each(function()
{
     var object = creatObject($(this).val());
     $(this).change(function()
     {
           if($(this).is(':checked'))
           {
                 var object = creatObject($(this).val());
           }
           else
           {
                 object.remove();
           }
     });
});
```

But i want to have another checkbox who permit to check or uncheck all the checkbox who's name is "*nameCheckbox*" and pass by the function change of all the element. So i have this code.

```
$("[name='allCheck']").change(function()
{
        var selectAll = false;
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            selectAll = true;
        }

        $("input[name='nameCheckbox']").each(function()
        {
            if(selectAll)
            {
                 $(this).prop('checked',true);
            }
            else
            {
                 $(this).prop('checked',false);
            }
            //And here i want to do something like $(this).change();
        });           
    });
```

Thank you

Comment: `And here i want to do something like $(this).change();` no problem with that: do it.

Comment: @VisioN, actually, I think you are right. $(this).change() should work

Comment: Why do you iterate over all the checkboxes in order to attach a `change` event? Do it in one line : `$("input[name='nameCheckbox']").change(function(){...`

Comment: Yes but it don't work if i do that it just doing nothing i want to launch the function change of the element.

Comment: @AmmarCSE Certainly. It will be the same as `$(this).trigger('change')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).change()` should work, according to [change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

> Description: Bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event,
>   **or trigger that event on an element.**

This is effectively the same as using [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$(this).trigger('change');
```